# Can Openlayers style vector polygons with every vertex of the polygon represented as a small circle or dot?

Tags: openlayers-2

Can Openlayers style vector polygons with every vertex of the polygon represented as a small circle or dot?

Comment: Do you need this Vector layers only, or will a solution of styling WMS services suffice?

Comment: You can do this but it would not be simple.  I would start with some of the functions inside the edit polygon tool.  It performs this visualization, but you would have to repurpose it.